# Prononciation de voyelles en chantant

Tags: prononciation, musique

Quelles sont les différences de prononciation de voyelles entre langage parlé et chanté ?

Par exemple, en allemand, il y a des règles pour la prononciation chantée de diphthongues comme "ei=aaaaaaaaaae", il y a d'autres règles pour traiter les voyelles très courtes qui sont pourtant chantées sur une note longue.

Evidemment, ce type de règle ne s'applique à tous les cas et n'est pas obligatoire, mais existe-t-il des règles heuristiques pour la prononciation chantée de voyelles comme "oi" ou "e" terminal sur une note longue ?

Comment: En anglais et en allemand, on modifie la prononciation des diphtongues en chantant parce que les diphtongues ne sonnent pas aussi bien en chanson. Il n'y a aucune diphthongue en français.

Answer (score 6):

La prononciation en chant dépend essentiellement du style de chant. On prononcera différemment selon qu'il s'agisse de musique populaire ou classique par exemple.

Je n'ai pas en tête de cas où les voyelles sont modifiées en chant, mais les r sont souvent roulés au fond de la gorge en chant classique, alors qu'ils sont beaucoup plus discrets dans le langage parlé.

Answer (score 3):

Un point important à aborder lorsque l'on parle de chant, est d'abord l'**articulation**.

---

### Qu'entend-t-on par articulation?

Pour articuler inutile de grimacer exagérément. Articuler est un travail effectué principalement avec la langue.

Le point d'articulation est le lieu où la langue se situe dans la bouche et où la vibration est la plus sensible pour les voyelles, et le lieu de plus grand rapprochement ou de contact pour les consonnes.

Les points d'articulation des voyelles se représentent sur un quadrilatère, le quadrilatère vocalique. Le **/ i /** est la voyelle la plus antérieure et située le plus en haut. Le **/ â /** est la voyelle la plus postérieure et située le plus en bas.

### Que nous apprennent les chercheurs en phonétique articulatoire et en acoustique?

Les points d'articulation se déplacent

En langage parlé les (consonnes) occlusives dont I' occlusion est réalisée par Ie dos de la langue appuyé contre la voûte palatine, ont un lieu d' occlusion pouvant en fait aller de la région prépalatale a la région vélaire, et étant déterminé par la nature de la voyelle qui précède ou qui suit. En français par exemple, Ie **/ k /** de "qui" est antériorisé sous I' influence du **/ i /**, tandis que Ie **/ k /** de cou est vélarisé."'(Nève 2OO3)

Et inversement, le **/ a /** de "page" est antériorisé par l'articulation bilabiale du **/ p /** alors que le **/a/** de "gage" reste postérieur.

Les voyelles, elles aussi, s'influencent. Par exemple, dans le mot sillage le **/ i /** précédant le **/ a /** antériorise celui-ci.
Le voisinage de certaines consonnes modifie la justesse des voyelles.

En langage parlé, la fréquence fondamentale des voyelles est influencée globalement par la consonne précédente : les obstruantes sourdes ont pour effet d'élever sensiblement leur fréquence fondamentale moyenne (4 à 8 Hz) tandis que les obstruantes sonores produisent l'effet inverse.( Di Cristo 1976).

Alors que chez des chanteurs lyriques professionnels, cet effet délétère des consonnes sur la justesse des voyelles est nettement atténué et dépassent rarement 1Hz .(Scotto Di Carlo 1977).

De ces mesures de laboratoire, peut-on conclure que les apprentis chanteurs, qui articulent fréquemment en chant comme en langage parlé, peuvent manifester des erreurs de justesse par pure raison articulatoire?

### L'articulation en chant

Afin d'homogénéiser la production sonore et de maintenir la justesse le chanteur lyrique antériorise les points d'articulation du langage chanté. (Hutois 2012)
Comment pratiquent les chanteurs pour antérioriser le son?

Par un travail de la langue, le chanteur déplace vers l'avant du palais les points d'articulation des voyelles postérieures ( **/ â, a,ê, o /** ) et des consonnes obstruantes dorso vélaires postérieures ( **/k, g /**). Il faut noter qu' en chant lyrique la voyelle/ i /est, quant à elle, légèrement assombrie.(Hutois 2012)

Pour réaliser ces déplacement de l'articulation les chanteurs s'appuient sur leurs perceptions sensorielles. En cherchant à ressentir les vibrations sonores de toutes les voyelles dans la même zone antérieure de la bouche, ils éviteront l'effet délétère sur la justesse de consonnes ou de voyelles qui suivent ou précédent la voyelle chantée. De cette manière la justesse sera au rendez-vous et le "rubans sonore" gagnera en homogénéité.

Source: [marie.hutois.over-blog.com](http://marie.hutois.over-blog.com/2014/04/articuler.html)